# System.InvalidOperationException in Output Window

Tags: c#

I constantly get the following message in my output/debug windows. The app doesn't crash but I was wondering what the deal with it is:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

my code :sol.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Sol
    {


        public LinkedList<int> tower1 = new LinkedList<int>();
        public LinkedList<int> tower2 = new LinkedList<int>();
        public LinkedList<int> tower3 = new LinkedList<int>();

        public static LinkedList<string> BFS = new LinkedList<string>();
        public static LinkedList<string> DFS = new LinkedList<string>();
        public static LinkedList<string> IDS = new LinkedList<string>();


        public int depth;

        public LinkedList<Sol> neighbors;

        public Sol()
        {
        }

        public Sol(LinkedList<int> tower1, LinkedList<int> tower2, LinkedList<int> tower3)
        {
            this.tower1 = tower1;
            this.tower2 = tower2;
            this.tower3 = tower3;

            neighbors = new LinkedList<Sol>();
        }

        public virtual void getneighbors()
        {

            Sol temp = this.copy();
            Sol neighbor1 = this.copy();
            Sol neighbor2 = this.copy();
            Sol neighbor3 = this.copy();
            Sol neighbor4 = this.copy();
            Sol neighbor5 = this.copy();
            Sol neighbor6 = this.copy();





            if (temp.tower1.Count != 0)
            {

                if (neighbor1.tower2.Count != 0)
                {
                    if (neighbor1.tower1.First.Value < neighbor1.tower2.First.Value)
                    {
                        neighbor1.tower2.AddFirst(neighbor1.tower1.First);
                        neighbor1.tower1.RemoveFirst();
                        neighbors.AddLast(neighbor1);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    neighbor1.tower2.AddFirst(neighbor1.tower1.First);
                    neighbor1.tower1.RemoveFirst();
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor1);
                }



                if (neighbor2.tower3.Count != 0)
                {
                    if (neighbor2.tower1.First.Value < neighbor2.tower3.First.Value)
                    {
                        neighbor2.tower3.AddFirst(neighbor2.tower1.First);
                        neighbor2.tower1.RemoveFirst();
                        neighbors.AddLast(neighbor2);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    neighbor2.tower3.AddFirst(neighbor2.tower1.First);
                    neighbor2.tower1.RemoveFirst();
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor2);
                }

            }




            //-------------

            if (temp.tower2.Count != 0)
            {


                if (neighbor3.tower1.Count != 0)
                {
                    if (neighbor3.tower2.First.Value < neighbor3.tower1.First.Value)
                    {
                        neighbor3.tower1.AddFirst(neighbor3.tower2.First);
                        neighbor3.tower2.RemoveFirst();
                        neighbors.AddLast(neighbor3);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    neighbor3.tower1.AddFirst(neighbor3.tower2.First);
                    neighbor3.tower2.RemoveFirst();
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor3);
                }



                if (neighbor4.tower3.Count != 0)
                {
                    if (neighbor4.tower2.First.Value < neighbor4.tower3.First.Value)
                    {
                        neighbor4.tower3.AddFirst(neighbor4.tower2.First);
                        neighbor4.tower2.RemoveFirst();
                        neighbors.AddLast(neighbor4);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    neighbor4.tower3.AddFirst(neighbor4.tower2.First);
                    neighbor4.tower2.RemoveFirst();
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor4);
                }


            }


            //------------------------

            if (temp.tower3.Count() != 0)
            {


                if (neighbor5.tower1.Count() != 0)
                {
                    if (neighbor5.tower3.ElementAtOrDefault(0) < neighbor5.tower1.ElementAtOrDefault(0))
                    {
                        neighbor5.tower1.AddFirst(neighbor5.tower3.First);
                        neighbor5.tower3.RemoveFirst();
                        neighbors.AddLast(neighbor5);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    neighbor5.tower1.AddFirst(neighbor5.tower3.First);
                    neighbor5.tower3.RemoveFirst();
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor5);
                }



                if (neighbor6.tower2.Count() != 0)
                {
                    if (neighbor6.tower3.ElementAtOrDefault(0) < neighbor6.tower2.ElementAtOrDefault(0))
                    {
                        neighbor6.tower2.AddFirst(neighbor6.tower3.First);
                        neighbor6.tower3.RemoveFirst();
                        neighbors.AddLast(neighbor6);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    neighbor6.tower2.AddFirst(neighbor6.tower3.First);
                    neighbor6.tower3.RemoveFirst();
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor6);
                }

            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {

            string str;

            str = "tower1" + tower1.ToString() + "   tower2" + tower2.ToString() + "   tower3" + tower3.ToString();


            return str;

        }


        public Sol copy()
        {

            Sol So;
            LinkedList<int> l1 = new LinkedList<int>();
            LinkedList<int> l2 = new LinkedList<int>();
            LinkedList<int> l3 = new LinkedList<int>();


            for (int i = 0; i <= this.tower1.Count() - 1; i++)
            {

                l1.AddLast(tower1.ElementAt(i));

            }



            for (int i = 0; i <= this.tower2.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                l2.AddLast(tower2.ElementAt(i));

            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= this.tower3.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                l3.AddLast(tower3.ElementAt(i));

            }


            So = new Sol(l1, l2, l3);
            return So;

        }



        public bool Equals(Sol sol)
        {

            if (this.tower1.Equals(sol.tower1) & this.tower2.Equals(sol.tower2) & this.tower3.Equals(sol.tower3))
                return true;

            return false;

        }


        public virtual bool containedin(Stack<Sol> vec)
        {

            bool found = false;

            for (int i = 0; i <= vec.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (vec.ElementAt(i).tower1.Equals(this.tower1) && vec.ElementAt(i).tower2.Equals(this.tower2) && vec.ElementAt(i).tower3.Equals(this.tower3))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }

            }

            return found;
        }




        public virtual bool breadthFirst(Sol start, Sol goal)
        {
            Stack<Sol> nextStack = new Stack<Sol>();
            Stack<Sol> traversed = new Stack<Sol>();
            bool found = false;

            start.depth = 0;
            nextStack.Push(start);


            while (nextStack.Count != 0)
            {


                Sol sol = nextStack.Pop();

                BFS.AddFirst("poped State:" + sol.ToString() + "level " + sol.depth);

                traversed.Push(sol);

                if (sol.Equals(goal))
                {
                    found = true;
                    BFS.AddFirst("Goal:" + sol.ToString());

                    break;
                }

                else
                {

                    sol.getneighbors();

                    foreach (Sol neighbor in sol.neighbors)
                    {

                        if (!neighbor.containedin(traversed) && !neighbor.containedin(nextStack))
                        {
                            neighbor.depth = (sol.depth + 1);
                            nextStack.Push(neighbor);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return found;
        }


        public virtual bool depthFirst(Sol start, Sol goal)
        {
            Stack<Sol> nextStack = new Stack<Sol>();
            Stack<Sol> traversed = new Stack<Sol>();

            bool found = false;

            start.depth = 0;
            nextStack.Push(start);

            while (nextStack.Count != 0)
            {
                //Dequeue next State for comparison
                //And add it 2 list of traversed States
                Sol sol = nextStack.Pop();


                DFS.AddFirst("poped State:" + sol.ToString() + "level " + sol.depth);


                traversed.Push(sol);


                if (sol.Equals(goal))
                {
                    found = true;
                    DFS.AddFirst("Goal:" + sol.ToString());
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    sol.getneighbors();
                    foreach (Sol neighbor in sol.neighbors)
                    {
                        if (!neighbor.containedin(traversed) && !neighbor.containedin(nextStack))
                        {
                            neighbor.depth = sol.depth + 1;
                            nextStack.Push(neighbor);
                        }



                    }
                }

            }
            return found;
        }


        public virtual bool iterativedeepening(Sol start, Sol goal)
        {
            bool found = false;




            for (int level = 0; ; level++)
            {

                Stack<Sol> nextStack = new Stack<Sol>();
                Stack<Sol> traversed = new Stack<Sol>();


                start.depth = 0;
                nextStack.Push(start);

                while (nextStack.Count != 0)
                {

                    Sol sol = nextStack.Pop();

                    IDS.AddFirst("poped State:" + sol.ToString() + "Level" + sol.depth);

                    traversed.Push(sol);

                    if (sol.Equals(goal))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        IDS.AddFirst("Goal:" + sol.ToString());

                        break;
                    }
                    else if (sol.depth < level)
                    {
                        sol.getneighbors();
                        foreach (Sol neighbor in sol.neighbors)
                        {
                            if (!neighbor.containedin(traversed) && !neighbor.containedin(nextStack))
                            {
                                neighbor.depth = sol.depth + 1;
                                nextStack.Push(neighbor);
                            } //end if
                        } //end for each

                    } //end else if
                } // end while

                if (found == true)
                    break;
            } // end for
            return found;
        }



    }
}
```

Just wondering if I may be doing something wrong somewhere or something. >>>

Comment: Slapping all of your code on the question like this will not get you any answers - you need to narrow it down for people (the exception will have a stack trace pointing to the problem function). Nor will having not accepted answers to your other questions (go through your other questions and click on to the check mark next to the answer that helped you most).

Comment: I need of anyone to help me (:

Comment: First suggestion. "Refactor your code!!".
Even if someone helps you out with this exception, it is very likely that you or someone else would again had to spend hours in understanding and/or debugging this code in case of any other exception or change.

Comment: I tried all possible ways to resolve my problem but I'm not sure of the cause of the emergence of the exception, where its exact location to fix.

Comment: @user318068: The one you didn't try is to boil your problem down to a small (25 lines), self-contained program that reproduces it. While doing so, you will very likely find the problem. And if you don't, you have the perfect piece of code to come back here and ask about.

Comment: @user318068 As a very quick way to cut the number of lines of code in half, remove unnecessary white space! It is at times like these I look fondly toward the future when I can edit questions to ease the agitation caused by my coding OCD.

Answer (score 2):

**First-chance Exceptions**
A first-chance exception indicates that something threw an exception - the debugger is reporting it because it gets to see all exceptions first. It then passes control back to the code that threw it - if that code doesn't handle the exception, the debugger will see it again as a second-chance exception and report it to you.

For more information on first- and second-chance exception handling, see [this Microsoft support article, KB105675](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675).

**Where is it coming from?**
Discovering which exact bit of code is doing this will require a little effort. Delete code bit by bit until the first-chance exception goes away - this will identify the code that is resulting in the exception.

As to whether you are doing something wrong, it is unlikely. The fact that your application didn't crash suggests that the code throwing the exception is ultimately handling it as it is some sort of expected situation (for example, a rudimentary way of detecting if some key exists in a dictionary would be to access that key and see if it threw an exception). However, you'll only know for sure once you've identified the source of the exception and investigated as to whether you're using the relevant calls correctly.